# PHP extending to the MySQLI class

Tags: php, mysqli

I created a class where I extended my class to the mysqli class in PHP, and I was actually shocked to see these errors

```
Warning: Missing argument 1 for BeatBeast_Database::__construct(), called in C:\xampp\htdocs\beatbeast\login.php on line 11 and defined in C:\xampp\htdocs\beatbeast\includes\Db\BeatBeast_Db.php on line 6

Warning: Missing argument 2 for BeatBeast_Database::__construct(), called in C:\xampp\htdocs\beatbeast\login.php on line 11 and defined in C:\xampp\htdocs\beatbeast\includes\Db\BeatBeast_Db.php on line 6

Warning: Missing argument 3 for BeatBeast_Database::__construct(), called in C:\xampp\htdocs\beatbeast\login.php on line 11 and defined in C:\xampp\htdocs\beatbeast\includes\Db\BeatBeast_Db.php on line 6

Warning: Missing argument 4 for BeatBeast_Database::__construct(), called in C:\xampp\htdocs\beatbeast\login.php on line 11 and defined in C:\xampp\htdocs\beatbeast\includes\Db\BeatBeast_Db.php on line 6
```

Here's the BeatBeast_Db.php

```
<?php
    class BeatBeast_Database extends mysqli
    {

        protected $r = 'Something';
        public function __construct($db_host,$db_username,$db_password,$db_name)
        {
            parent::__construct($db_host,$db_username,$db_password,$db_name);

            if(mysqli_connect_error())
            {
                die('Connect Error (' . mysqli_connect_errno() . ')' . mysqli_connect_error());
            }
        }

        public function close()
        {
            $this->close();
        }

    }

    require_once("db_constants.inc.php");
    $conn = new BeatBeast_Database("localhost", "root", "myPass", "beatbeast");
```

This is my login.php

```
<?php require_once("./includes/Utilities.php") ;?>
<?php require_once("./includes/Db/DatabaseUtilities.php"); ?>
<?php require_once("./includes/Db/Accounts.php");?>
<?php require_once("./includes/Db/BeatBeast_Db.php"); ?>

<?php 
    if(isset($_POST['submit'])){
        require_once("./includes/process_form.inc.php");

        $hashedPass = crypt($password,$username);
        $accounts = new Accounts();
        $accounts->showMessage();
```

and line 11 is

```
$accounts = new Accounts();
```

If you guys are interested here's my Accounts class

require_once("BeatBeast_Db.php");

```
Class Accounts extends BeatBeast_Database
{
    private $accnt_id;
    private $username;
    private $email;

    function info()
    {

        echo "{$this->accnt_id} {$this->username} {$this->email}";
    }

    public static function getIdByUsername($username)
    {
        global $conn;
        $sql = "SELECT accnt_id FROM accounts WHERE username = '{$username}'";
        $rs = $conn->query($sql);
        $found = $rs->fetch_array();
        return $found;
    }

    public function showMessage(){
        echo "{$this->r}";
    }

    public static function getUsernameById($id)
    {
        global $conn;
            $sql = "SELECT username FROM accounts WHERE accnt_id = $id ";
        $rs = $conn->query($sql);
        $found = $rs->fetch_array();
        return $found;
    }

    public function getAccntId()
    {
        return $this->accnt_id;
    }

    public function getUsername()
    {
        return $this->username;
    }

    public function getEmail()
    {
        return $this->email;
    }
}
```

Comment: You need to show us line 11 of login.php

Comment: @EugenRieck there I updated my question

Answer (score 1):

If you look at the PHP reference for MySQLi (http://www.php.net/manual/en/class.mysqli.php), the original class constructor contains 6 parameters:

```
__construct ([ string $host = ini_get("mysqli.default_host") [, string $username = ini_get("mysqli.default_user") [, string $passwd = ini_get("mysqli.default_pw") [, string $dbname = "" [, int $port = ini_get("mysqli.default_port") [, string $socket = ini_get("mysqli.default_socket") ]]]]]] )
```

When extending MySQLi you have to define all of them, even if you are not using. Though, that's not what is causing the warning error.

In your case, you are calling `$accounts = new Accounts();` without defining any arguments. Though, `Accounts` class extents `BeatBeast_Database`. Therefore you need to pass all the `BeatBeast_Database` constructor parameters (`$db_host,$db_username,$db_password,$db_name`).

Answer (score 0):

Let's start with login.php, line 11

```
$accounts = new Accounts();
```

This calls the constructor of the `Accounts` class - which has none defined. Since

```
Class Accounts extends BeatBeast_Database
```

PHP falls back to the constructor of the `BeatBeast_Database` class:

```
public function __construct($db_host,$db_username,$db_password,$db_name)
```

which needs 4 parameters, but gets none - exactly what was in the error message. You will need to change line 11 of `login.php` to

```
$accounts = new Accounts(DB_HOST, DB_USER, DB_PASSWD, DB_NAME);
```

or however the constants you define in `db_constants.inc.php` are clled.